# Pasting multiple columns data under one column

Tags: excel, vba

Data is in the below format,

[image]

I need data in the below format,

[image]

I used the below macro but it is not working,

```
Sub CombineColumns1()
    'updateby Extendoffice 20151030
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim xLastRow As Integer
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRng = Application.InputBox("please select the data range", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xLastRow = xRng.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1
    For i = 4 To xRng.Columns.Count
        For j = 1 To 3
            Range(xRng.Cells(j, i), xRng.Cells(xRng.Columns(i).Rows.Count, i)).Cut
            ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=xRng.Cells(xLastRow, 1)
            xLastRow = xLastRow + xRng.Columns(i).Rows.Count
        Next
        j = 1
        i = i + 2
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: "...it is not working." - How so? Is it giving you an error? If so, what error and what line? Is it working, but giving unexpected results? etc...

Comment: This can be done with a formula if you are interested.

Comment: Remove the `On Error...` line and see where the error is.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm interested if that matters? I think I could do this, but you seem to be WAY better at array formulas than I am.

Comment: @scott craner i am interested.

Comment: @ brucewayne only name column is being copied and pasted

Comment: @Kyle no array formula just some math with an INDEX formula.

Comment: record a macro, to record yourself doing the iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a formula I put the original data in rows 1 and 2.  Then in Row 4 I put only the three headers.

Then in A5 I put this formula:

```
=INDEX($2:$2,((ROW(1:1) - 1) * 3) + 1 + (COLUMN(A:A)-1))
```

Then drag/filled over two columns and down two rows.

This formula uses the entire second row as its reference for the data so no matter how many columns it will be included and only needs to be drag/filled down a sufficient number of rows.

If the data pattern is different than every three columns then change the `3` to the number of columns in the pattern.

[image]

---

As per your comments:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($2:$4,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(MATCH("ZZZ",$1:$1)/3))+1,(MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),MATCH("ZZZ",$1:$1)/3) *3)+1 + (COLUMN(A:A)-1)),"")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

To go rows first then columns flip the two row references:

```
=INDEX($2:$4,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,3)+1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/3)*3+1+COLUMN(A:A)-1)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: thanks it is working. But i have a small problem. If there are multiple rows of data then how to write formula. In the above example i have given only one row of data

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @commander420 Is there a set number of groups per row?  Or are they arbitrary?

Comment: @Scott Craner Number of rows are constant, there will be only three rows of data

Comment: So three rows and an unlimited number of columns? @commander420

Comment: @Scott Craner yes

Comment: @commander420 remember that if this works and is the method you use to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  If someone give you vba that works and you use that then choose that one.

Comment: @Scott Craner is it possible to copy jason,tim,xander data after david,scott and dawn

Comment: @Scott Craner Thank you so much, your solution is working. If there are 5 rows instead of three what should i change in the formula

Comment: @commander420 You have changed the question many times.  This is not usually acceptable on this site.  Try to figure it out.  If you cannot then come back and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA solution (just in case you choose not to go with Scott's excellent formula) would be:

```
Sub CombineColumns1()
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim xNextRow As Long
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveSheet
        xTxt = .RangeSelection.Address
        Set xRng = Application.InputBox("please select the data range", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
        If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        j = xRng.Columns(1).Column
        For i = 4 To xRng.Columns.Count Step 3
            'Need to recalculate the last row, as some of the final columns may not have data in all rows
            xNextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            .Range(xRng.Cells(1, i), xRng.Cells(xRng.Rows.Count, i + 2)).Copy .Cells(xNextRow, j)
            .Range(xRng.Cells(1, i), xRng.Cells(xRng.Rows.Count, i + 2)).Clear
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Note:  The code is assuming that the user is **not** including the headings when selecting the data range.